# Issue with dateAdapter for specific language only

Tags: angular, datepicker, locale

I am using Angular material date picker and I have a problem with specific language only - ka. Take a look at the following example:

```
  constructor(
    private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>,
    public noticesService:NoticesService, 
    public datepipe: DatePipe,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    public router: Router) {
      this.dateAdapter.setLocale('fr');
    }
```

works as it should, take a look at the screenshot language changes and now the second language:

```
  constructor(
    private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>,
    public noticesService:NoticesService, 
    public datepipe: DatePipe,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    public router: Router) {
      this.dateAdapter.setLocale('ka');
    }
```

Language doesn't change and stays in English. This problem occurs only with ka language, all other languages work like a charm, I honestly have no clue what can be an issue here and how to edit things in order for it to work.

[image: French one]
[image: Georgian one]

This is datepicker HTML template:

```
          <mat-form-field class="fullWidth padder forSelectLabel" appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>დაბადების თარიღი</mat-label>
            <div class="forSelect">
              <img class="doc-icon" style="max-width: 30px" [src]="iconPath + 'date.svg'">
              <input [(ngModel)]="dateOfBirth" placeholder="დაბადების თარიღი" autocomplete="off" matInput
                [matDatepicker]="picker" name="dateOfBirth">
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
            </div>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: You can see example here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker-locale-vfxb94?file=src/app/lazy/datepicker-form/datepicker-form.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this instead?

```js
this.dateAdapter.setLocale('ka-GE');
```

Comment: Yes, it worked, problem is 'ka'

Comment: @nevaehteekay, great!

Comment: But I need another language not 'kn-in', 'ka' is not working

Comment: Not sure what do you mean?

Comment: 'kn-in' is different language, I want to change locale to 'ka' which exists, but whenever I write this.dateAdapter.setLocale('ka'); my language wont change and it stays on english

Comment: What language are you referring to?

Comment: Georgian, 'ka' ka-GE

Comment: this.dateAdapter.setLocale('ka-GE');

Comment: Already tried, it seems like Angular will work on any possible locales except 'ka' or 'ka-GE'

Comment: Looks like that to me too